# Failed to expand alias in Non-Interactive shell

Tags: bash, scripting, alias

I want to use some aliases in a non-interactive shell, after reading [this post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/158038/non-interactive-shell-expand-alias) and [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/224669/how-to-run-some-alias-command-in-bashs-non-interactive-mode). Here is my command:

```
bash -O expand_aliases -c 'source ~/.bashrc; <some alias>'
```

and here is my `.bashrc`:

```
 # Bash History
 HISTSIZE=1000
 HISTFILESIZE=2000
 # Colorful Prompt
 PS1='\[\033[01;34m\]\w\n\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\] > '
 # Aliases
 alias ls='ls --color=auto -A -I NTUSER.\* -I ntuser.\*'
 alias echo='echo -e'
 alias docker='"/mnt/c/Program Files/Docker/Docker/resources/bin/docker.exe"'
 alias docker-compose='"/mnt/c/Program Files/Docker/Docker/resources/bin/docker-compose.exe"'
```

I `echo`ed something in `.bashrc` and am sure that `source ~/.bashrc` worked, but the aliases just refused to expand. I also tried:

```
bash -O expand_aliases -c shopt
```

to ensure that the option `expand_aliases` is set to on.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The very simple workaround is to use a function instead of an alias. There are many situations where functions are superior to aliases, and as far as I can tell none where the opposite is true.

```
 docker () { "/mnt/c/Program Files/Docker/Docker/resources/bin/docker.exe" "$@"; }
 docker-compose () { "/mnt/c/Program Files/Docker/Docker/resources/bin/docker-compose.exe" "$@"; }
```

(I have refused to port your `ls` and `echo` aliases - they seem more harm than good.)

Answer (score 0):

The `.bashrc` is executed for interactive shells only.

This is what I've done. Create a new file `.bash_env` in your home directory. Put all your aliases there, e.g.:

```
shopt -s expand_aliases
alias egrep='egrep --color=auto'
alias fgrep='fgrep --color=auto'
alias grep='grep --color=auto'
alias ll='ls -l --color=auto'
alias ls='ls --color=auto'
alias vi='vim'
```

Then reference it in your `.bash_profile` (put a real pathname there, of course):

```
 export BASH_ENV='/home/username/.bash_env'
```

(Log out and log in to activate)

---

`BASH_ENV` in the manpage:

> If this parameter is set when bash is executing a shell script, its
>   value is interpreted as a filename containing commands to initialize
>   the shell, as in ~/.bashrc.

and:

> When  bash  is  started  non-interactively,  to  run a shell script,
>   for example, it looks for the variable BASH_ENV in the environment,
>   expands its value if it
>   appears there, and uses the expanded value as the name of a file to read and execute.